# How to remove Dollar sign($) from Attribute's Value (in XML) using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML file in which $ sign is available in attribute's value:

```
     <data>
        <DWFOutput>
           <FormsXML>
              <print name="_Print">
                 <ExportDocument docType="PDF">
                    <ExportSection name="MD0001B1014" BinNum="0" >
                       <dataElement name=" Period" value="$Annual" />
                       <dataElement name="Effective" value="$55" />
                    </ExportSection>
                    <ExportSection name="VZ400030798" BinNum="0">
                       <dataElement name="CityS" value="$213" />
                       <dataElement name="Zip 13" value="$50" />
                    </ExportSection>
                    <ExportSection name="VZ00040798" BinNum="0" >
                       <dataElement name="DCT_JOBNAMES" value="$ ABCD" />
                       <dataElement name="Policy Number" value="$ 2504"  />
                       <dataElement name="States" value="CA  AL  " />
                    </ExportSection>
                 </ExportDocument>
              </print>
           </FormsXML>
        </DWFOutput>
     </data>
```

as per expectation, need to use XSLT code to remove "$" sign, So i have created below XSLT code for same, However am not getting expected response (i.e. $ sign has not been removed).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
           <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="/data/DWFOutput/FormsXML/print/ExportDocument/" > 
    <xsl:for-each select="ExportSection/dataElement">
            <xsl:variable name="RemoveDollar" select="@value"/>
                 <!--<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'$dollar')"/>--> 
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($RemoveDollar,'$','')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>
I am beginner to XSLT, So can someone please help me here.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

> need to use XSLT code to remove "$" sign

If that's all you need to do, then do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '$', '')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```